# Nuxt(Vue) Apollo error handling using $apollo.query

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

In my nuxt application I'm trying to manually call a nuxt apollo (v. 4.0.1) query, and handle the resulting error. I've tried both an outer try catch, as well as the error method through the query, however, it doesnt seem to be reaching either handlers.

```
this.$apollo
        .query({
            query: baseCategoryChildren,
            variables: { id: bCat.sys.id },
            errorPolicy: 'ignore',
            error(error, vm, key, type, options) {
                 console.log(error)
                 console.log(vm)
                 console.log(key)
                 console.log(type)
                 console.log(options)
             },
         })
```

In the example apove, none of the console logs are outputtet, instead, all I get is the default Apollo error message in console.

```
app.730eca1.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 429
    at new n (app.730eca1.js:2)
    at app.730eca1.js:2
    at app.730eca1.js:2
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at app.730eca1.js:2
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.broadcastQueries (app.730eca1.js:2)
    at app.730eca1.js:2
```

I'm trying to check for the status code in the error response to handle correctly, but i can't seem to geht to the error in the code.

Any idea as to why the error method isn't being called?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an errorHandler in the apollo section of your `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
   // ===
   apollo: {
        clientConfigs: {
            default: {
                httpEndpoint: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/graphql`
            }
        },
        errorHandler: '~/plugins/errorhandler.apollo.js'
    },
   // other nuxt config like loading, css, plugins
}
```

In `~/plugins/errorhandler.apollo.js` you can have something like

```js
export default (graphqlError, { store, error, redirect, route }) => {
    console.log({ graphqlError })

    const { networkError, message, gqlError, graphqlErrors } = graphqlError

    // handle error

    return error({ statusCode: 503, message: message })
}
```